# Scroll over Text box

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to have my form autoscroll and when the cursor is over textbox I cannot scroll with the mousewheel. How can i scroll even when the cursor is on the textbox? Thank you :D

Comment: And how are you currently trying to achieve your aim? We can't tell you what's wrong with what you're doing if we don't know what you're doing.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have actually no idea, i have never worked with scrolls before. I have enabled the autoscroll on my form and on load it scrolls to the bottom of the form. I just put focus on the first item to scroll to top on load. But don't know what to do when the cursor is on a textbox. There is no document on those, i am still searcing for it.

Comment: See if this can do the job: [How do I scroll over items in a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697028/how-do-i-scroll-over-items-in-a-panel?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: sorry but still didn't work, it just stops at a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol, I can just press CTRL and scroll, it skips everything and scroll the whole from just normally. Thank you guys for replying and helped me. :D